# Google Chart: Column Chart, Pie Chart Opacity

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

As per title above, is that possible to set the opacity of the chart?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the opacity of the element that contains the chart.

Answer (score 0):

backgroundColor: 'transparent',

i.e
var options = {
          title: 'Defect Classification',
                            is3D: true,
                           'width':600,
                           'height':300,
              backgroundColor: '#EFEFFB',
              //backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        };